# set a variable when all nested api give the result in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

In my function i am calling nested api inside a for loop and i want to set a variable when my for loop api calling will completed. How i can achieve this in angular 2 .

```
this.cMSService.listServiceByProductAndParentService(productId, parentServiceId).subscribe(res => {
            //console.log("Previous Services are",res);
            for (let j = 0; j < res.length; j++) {
                if (res[j].has_children) {
                    this.cMSService.listServiceByProductAndParentService(productId, res[j].id).subscribe(childService => {
                        res = res.concat(childService);
                        console.log(childService);
                        this.cMSService.listServiceByProduct(productId).subscribe(prodService => {
                            //console.log("Product Service response is", prodService);
                            for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                                let servicePrices = prodService.find(tempProdService => tempProdService.id == res[i].id);
                                if(servicePrices){
                                res[i].prices = servicePrices.prices;
                                }
                            }
                            //console.log("After Service Response is", res);
                        })
                    })
                }
                else {
                    this.cMSService.listServiceByProduct(productId).subscribe(prodService => {
                        //console.log("Product Service response is", prodService);
                        for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                            let servicePrices = prodService.find(tempProdService => tempProdService.id == res[i].id);
                            //console.log("Services Price are ", servicePrices, res[i].id);
                            if (servicePrices) {
                                res[i].prices = servicePrices.prices;
                            }
                        }
                        //console.log("After Service Response is", res);
                    })
                }
            }

            this.services = res;
            console.log("Response is",res);
```

I want to set the variable when my api call finishes and the second thing is that when i am updating my **res** length . my for loop is still iterating to its previous value.

Comment: try using `distinctUntilChanged` opearator for the second api call

Comment: If you want to wait for all of the nested requests to complete, use `flatMap` and return e.g. `Observable.combineLatest` of all of the individual requests. Then you can `.subscribe` to the combined result of all requests, which will be your `res` array.